# Qt Symbian etel3rdparty library

Tags: qt, symbian

I am new to symbian environment, I am trying to build an application using Qt Symbian, I need to use etel3rdparty.lib and header also, I have included the lib path and include path also, but I am getting a lot of compilation error.

Like as follows:

```
from c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32const.h:9, 
from c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:8, 
from c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32std.h:13, 
from c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32base.h:8, 
from c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/etel3rdparty.h:20, 
from ..\AutoStart\dialog.cpp:10: 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32def.h:872: error: 'Int64' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32def.h:883: error: 'Uint64' does not name a type 
In file included from c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:8, 
from c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32std.h:13, 
from c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32base.h:8, 
from c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/etel3rdparty.h:20, 
from ..\AutoStart\dialog.cpp:10: 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32const.h:860: error: 'TInt64' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32const.h:871: error: 'TInt64' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32const.h:882: error: 'TUint64' does not name a type 
In file included from c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32std.h:13, 
from c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32base.h:8, 
from c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/etel3rdparty.h:20, 
from ..\AutoStart\dialog.cpp:10: 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:41: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:74: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:91: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:112: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:129: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:146: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:1066: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:1067: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:1068: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:1069: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:1070: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:1071: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:1072: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:1073: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:1074: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:1075: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:1076: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:1077: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:1078: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:1081: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type 
c:\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\include/e32cmn.h:1082: error: 'IMPORT_C' does not name a type
```

Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Please wrap the error output in quote tags for readability (select the text and pres ctrl-Q or press the "blockquote" (double apostrophe) button between the "hyperlink" and "code sample" buttons

Comment: What compiler are you using? Int64 etc. are defined in e32def.h (where you have your first error). It used '#if defined(__ GCC32 __)' constructs to do so, so one of these might be undefined.